# I can't find the Nash equilibrium of this $3 \times 2$ game.

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

*Sorry for my English, I am French but i couldn't find help on the French website (so I am here).*

I have a question about this two-player game:

$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
 & y_1 & y_2 \\
\hline
x_1 & a,0 & a,0 \\
x_2 & 1,-1 & -1,1 \\
x_3 & -1,1 & 1,-1
\end{array}
$$

When $a<0$ and $a>1$ it's easy because using domination we can find the Nash equilibrium (mixed), but when $0 \leq a \leq 1$ this is more difficult.

If $(p_1, p_2, 1-p_1-p_2)$ is the strategy of the player $1$ and $(q, 1-q)$ the strategy of the player $2$, by the indifference theorem for player $1$ I have
$$
E(x_1) = E(x_2) = E(x_3) \iff a = 2q-1 = -2q+1
$$
and for player $2$ I have 
$$
E(y_1) = E(y_2) \iff -p_2 + (1-p_1-p_2) = p_2 - (1-p_1-p_2)
$$
**What is the Nash equilibrium (mixed and pure) of this game for $0 \leq a \leq 1$?** I can't solve this equation...

Answer (score 1):

For $a \gt 0$, try Player 1 playing $x_1$ all the time and Player 2 playing $y_1$ and $y_2$ with equal probability

Comment: Thank you for your response. But how did you find this ? We can't find q which verify : $$ a = 2q-1 = -2q+1 $$

Comment: I think that your answer is wrong, because if a=0.5 the best strategy for player 1 is not $ x1 $... Are you sure ?

Comment: @Lingenieur: Your equation assumes that $x_2$ and $x_3$ have positive probability in the Nash equilibrium.  They do not when $a \gt 0$.  From your original table, there is a symmetry which suggests to me that $x_2$ and $x_3$ should be equally likely to be chosen as each other, and $y_1$ and $y_2$ should be equally likely to be chosen as each other, making the table effectively $$\begin{array}{c|cc}
 & y_{1\text{ or }2} \\
\hline
x_1 & a,0 \\
x_{2\text{ or }3} & 0,0 \end{array}$$

Comment: @Lingenieur: If Player 2 is choosing $y_1$ and $y_2$ with equal probability and $a=\frac12$, can you find a strategy for Player $1$ which gives an expected return greater than $\frac12$?

Comment: So you are saying that we can replace 2 symmetrical columns (for player 2) or 2 symmetrical lines (for player 1), by 0 ?

Comment: @Lingenieur: You asked for a Nash equilibrium, and I gave that in my original answer.  You then asked how I found it. I replied in a comment that it was the combined symmetry of the table which suggested this to me.

Comment: Yes if a=1/2, i can choose $x2$ : the player 1 will win 1 instead 1/2. If player 1 choose x1, he will win 1/2. A nash equilibrium is the best response for each players...

Comment: @Lingenieur, If Player 2 is choosing $y_1$ and $y_2$ with equal probability and Player 1 chooses $x_2$ then Player 1's expected return is $ +1\times \frac12 -1\times\frac12 = 0$ which is less than $a$.

Comment: So in summary: a gaming matrix is equivalent to a matrix in which all symetrical rows and columns are replaced by 0. This simplifies the matrix. Then nash equilibrium can be calculated by the conventional method using the equality of average for mixed strategies, and trying each stratégéies for pure strategies. Is it right?

Comment: @Lingenieur: I will not say that as a general rule, but it seems to work here, and does suggest what you can then check is a Nash equilibrium.

Comment: I have two last question please : what is the conventional method to verify if the pair of mixed strategies is a nash equilibrium in this case (becauseof the probability are not positive so you can't use equality of average) ? And when you say choosing $y1$ and $y2$ with equal probabily, you mean $y1$ = $y2$ = 1/2 But why can't i choose $y1 = 1$ ans $y2 = 0$ or $y1 = 0.20$ ans $y2 = 0.80$ (these columns are symetric so no matter the column We choose the strategy will always optimal. ?

Comment: I honestly do not pretend and I'm sorry if these questions are stupid.

Comment: Forget the equations for a minute and think about why Henry's answer is correct. Remember: a Nash equilibrium is a pair of mutual best responses. Equivalently, a pair of mixed strategies are an equilibrium if and only if all pure strategies played with positive probability are best responses. If player 2 mixed uniformly then player 1 gets 0 from the bottom two rows and (always) gets $a>0$ from the two top. Against the top row, player 2 is indifferent (so any mixture is a best response). Thus this is an equilibrium. Use http://banach.lse.ac.uk to solve games and refine your intuition.

Comment: So, any mixture of probabilities between $y1$ et $y2$ is a best answer. But with $y1=0.2$ et $y2=0.8$ $E(x1) = a$, $E(x2) = -0.6$ and $E(x3) = 0.6$. So if $a=1/2$, $x3$ is the best response for player $1$. $x1$ is always best response for player $1$ if and only if $y1=y2=1/2$. no ?

Comment: Please, i just want to know if $y1 = y2 = 1/2$ always ?

Comment: anybody can help me please ?

Comment: (@ RahulSavani) : you meant "a pair of mixed strategies $U,V$ are an equilibrium if and only if knowing that player $1$ chose $U$, player $2$ best choice is strategy $V$, and conversely if player $2$ chose the strategy $V$, then player $1$ best choice is to keep the strategy $U$". and here, in practice, it is easy to show that Henry answer is such a pair whenever $a \ge 0$.  (@Lingenieur)